# Removing duplicates with array_unique

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I created a image uploader which works by remote, so whenever a user enters a bunch of links, I want to prevent duplicate links being added so that the image isn't copied twice and is removed so it leaves the links to be unique without any duplicates.

```
$break = explode("\n", $links);
$count = count($break);

$unique_images = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    array_push($unique_images, $break[$i]); 
}

array_unique($unique_images);
```

The rest of the code works, but I'm just not getting why it isn't working, I also tried a `foreach` loop but that didn't help as well.

I have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` but there are no errors. I use `var_dump` on the array and I get this:

```
array(3) 
{ 
     [0]=> string(48) "http://localhost:8888/images/img/wallpaper-1.jpg" 
     [1]=> string(48) "http://localhost:8888/images/img/wallpaper-1.jpg" 
     [2]=> string(48) "http://localhost:8888/images/img/wallpaper-1.jpg" 
}
```

How come the `array_unique` doesn't remove any duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) **returns** a new array, it does not modify the array in place:

> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

```
$unique_images = array_unique($unique_images);
```

Answer (score 4):

`array_unique` **returns** the filtered array, instead of altering it. Change your last line into:

```
$unique_images = array_unique($unique_images)
```

and it should be working.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do:

```
$unique_images = array_unique(explode("\n", $links));
```

The `array_unique` function returns a new array with duplicates removed. So you need to collect its return value.

Also `explode` returns you an *array* which you can directly feed to `array_unique`.

Comment: @Youbook: that would be a replacement for your entire code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$unique_images = array_unique($unique_images);
```

otherwise you're simply discarding the result